# Limit number of records allowed

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, max, record

I have a table "tbdetails" where students' details are kept. Put simply, I want to limit the table to only hold 10 records max. My form for the table "frmDetails" has the following OnCurrent Event but it did not work:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   Forms(Detail).MaxRecords = 10
End Sub
```

I looked online and found that but I could just so easily insert 11 and 12 records. Any answer is welcome, VBA is not required (if it is possible to go without it ) Can this be done simply from the properties menu or something?

---

**EDIT:**

Now when I saved I get

> Runtime error 438: Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method

So there is definitely something wrong here

Comment: What does doesn't work mean?

Comment: Create an autonumber field. set the table validation property
to [field]<=10 ?

Comment: @QHarr I mean it did not stop me from putting in more than 10 records

Comment: @QHarr But with autonumber if I delete a record autonumber doesn't reset increment. So If delete all records and start again I can't put in any students.

Comment: Good point well made. @AshleeDawg this is your arena.

Comment: Do you want to limit the amount of records that can be displayed, the amount that can be added, or the total amount? These all require different things.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Total amount. Only 10 at all can exist in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Me.AllowAdditions = (Nz(DCount("[IDFieldName]","[TableName]",""),0)<10)

End Sub
```

Based on comments is seems this is enough:

```
Me.AllowAdditions = (DCount("[IDFieldName]","[TableName]")<10)
```

Comment: No need for empty brackets `""` if you don't set any criteria to the DCount function.

Comment: No need for `Nz` either. `DCount` should never return Null (it returns 0 if no records exist)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yeah but looks like just a precaution. I might delete all records and start again

Comment: @USERNNNNN Did you read my comment? You don't need it, even if you delete all records...

Comment: @Eric von Asmuth I knew it did if there was no records based on criteria, was not sure what it did if the table itself had no records at all and no way to test at the time so I opted for the safe way.

Answer (score 2):

> *"I want to limit the table to only hold 10 records max."*

Apply a check constraint to the table so it will not accept more than 10 rows.

Create a throwaway procedure and run it once ...

```vba
Public Sub limit_rows()
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "ALTER TABLE tblDetails" & vbCrLf & _
        "ADD CONSTRAINT 10_rows_max" & vbCrLf & _
        "CHECK ((SELECT Count(*) FROM tblDetails) < 11);"
    Debug.Print strSql
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Never worked with constraints in Access; usually use SQL server as the actual DBMS and Access as the front end. One potential issue I see is that this approach will just throw an error while other approaches just disable the UI for adding records.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the total number of records that can be added in the table with a certain form, you could use the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone 'Clone because we don't want to move the current record
    If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast 'Initialize recordset
    If rs.RecordCount >= 10 Then
        Me.AllowAdditions = False
    Else
        Me.AllowAdditions = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the recordset? With just `If Me.Recordset.RecordCount >= 10 Then Me.AllowAdditions = False` it works. Do you use it to make sure `RecordCount` works?

Comment: The recordset might not be fully initialized on current. In that case, `RecordCount` might be too low. It's to make sure `RecordCount` is accurate.

Comment: Yes, I tought that. Sometimes `RecordCount` fails even in Recordset objects, and we have to do the `MoveLast,MoveFirst` thing. But probably, with a table with just 10 records, not sure it it's worth it.. Anyways, your code works perfect! :)

Comment: Say is it possible to use an integer that increments every time a record is added and does not allow its own value to exceed 10?

Comment: That's a totally different question (and not recommended, since you would reuse the same numbers).

Comment: Eric, you could simplify this `Me.AllowAdditions = (rs.RecordCount < 10)`

Comment: @KostasK. That's certainly valid, and faster. I tend to not use it here, since it's harder to understand for beginners. I try to be as explicit as possible in my code over optimizing  for the minimum amount of assignments and comparisons.

Comment: I would skip the recordset/recordcount altogether and use `DCount`

Comment: @SunKnight0 That's a bad plan. `.RecordCount` reuses the already loaded records and filters. `DCount` doesn't.

Comment: It is a table with less than 10 records. Performance is not an issue. On the other hand, the unreliability of `.RecordCount ` is. For example `rs.MoveLast` will cause an error is there are no records so you have to check for EOF AND BOF first before using any Moves on the recordselt..

Comment: That's easily fixed (only the `EOF` check is necessary). It's a matter of preference. This code will work on any form without adjustment, while a `DCount` must be altered for every form, and can't handle things like forms bound to recordsets without a recordsource.

Comment: My understanding is that the recordset could have records and still have the cursor at `EOF`, so I generally check for both `BOF` and `EOF` to verify no records, but I have been doing this since Access 2000 so things may have changed. Then again, you just care about `MoveLast` not erroring and not really whether the recordset is empty or not so I see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a little more.

See in-line comments for usage:

```
Public Sub SetFormAllowAdditions( _
    ByVal frm As Form, _
    Optional ByVal RecordCountMax As Long = 1)

' Limit count of records in (sub)form to that of RecordCountMax.
' 2016-10-26, Cactus Data ApS, CPH
'
' Call in (sub)form:
'
'   Private Sub LimitRecords()
'       Const RecordsMax As Long = 5
'       Call SetFormAllowAdditions(Me.Form, RecordsMax)
'   End Sub
'
'   Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
'       Call LimitRecords
'   End Sub
'
'   Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
'       Call LimitRecords
'   End Sub
'
'   Private Sub Form_Current()
'       Call LimitRecords
'   End Sub
'
'   Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'       Call LimitRecords
'   End Sub
'
' If the record count of a subform is to be limited, also
' the parent form must be adjusted:
'
'   Private Sub Form_Current()
'       Call SetFormAllowAdditions(Me.Form)
'   End Sub
'

    Dim AllowAdditions  As Boolean

    With frm
        AllowAdditions = (.RecordsetClone.RecordCount < RecordCountMax)
        If AllowAdditions <> .AllowAdditions Then
            .AllowAdditions = AllowAdditions
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That also did not work; I just added 2, 3 records extra and nothing happened.

Comment: @Gustav You're not fully loading the recordset (no `.MoveLast` before `.RecordCount`). That might lead to inconsistent behaviour (though it's hard to believe with only 10 records).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Not in my test, and usually the RecordsetClone is fully loaded. But you can never tell.